# Read file content from different package in JUnit

Tags: java, csv, junit

I am trying to read a file (which contains my data) in my JUnit code.

I have a source folder named "test" and under it are the two packages below

> com.junit.codes (JUnit codes)
>
> com.junit.codes.data (csv Files i.e. myData.csv)

My problem is I cant access the files under com.junit.codes.data.

I have tried using classLoader but it does not work.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I tried getClass().getResource("/myData.csv") and getClass().getResource("/data/myData.csv") but both does not seem to work.

Comment: try this Paths.get("com/junit/codes/data/myData.csv"). If still error, track in stack trace what path it tried to look into.

Comment: How about `data/myData.csv` or `/com/junit/codes/data/MyData.csv`? `getClass().getResource()` should be relative to the current class' path.

Comment: @grsdev7, I dont have Paths API in my project and I am not allowed to add any 3rd party APIs.

Comment: @JiriTousek that does not work as well.

Comment: @jaypax123 : Paths is in Java 7 . Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

Comment: How are you running your JUint? Through an IDE (which one)? Or using some build system like Maven, Gradle etc. (which one)? Or directly invoking java?

Comment: @JiriTousek I am using eclipse to run my IDE. not using any build system.

Comment: You should probably add these to your question: 1) exact source structure (maybe with a screenshot) 2) Code you tried using so far (so others don't need to read comments to see it) 3) your classpath setting from the JUnit run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using a Maven based setup, do the following:

1. As non-Java files by default is not copied to the "target" folder in the "compile" phase you should add your csv-file to *src/test/resources/com/junit/codes/data*
2. From your test class you should now be able to do `getClass().getResourceAsStream("./data/myData.csv")` to open an input stream to read the data from.

**Example**:

```
package com.junit.codes;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.InputStream;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class ReadTest {
    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        try(final InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("./data/myData.csv")) {
            assertNotNull(inputStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is not using Maven, per the most recent comment.

Comment: Should work anyway if you ensure that whatever build mechanism your are using is in fact copying the file to the same "target"/"classes" folder as your .class-files

Comment: More generally, if the file is indeed on class path, whether copied or not. Anyways, just wanted to let you know that your assumption wasn't correct.

Comment: Sure @JiriTousek :-)